# jQuery Autocomplete remote source not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete in jQuery UI 1.9.2 that loads data from a remote source. It works when the data is within the same file in a  tag but as soon as I move it to a remote datasource I get no suggestions in the box. I am sure that the json is valid; I have checked its validity many times. I've also tried many of the solutions present here on this site and no luck so far.

the jQuery code (already connected to jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#q').autocomplete({
        source:'/json.php',
        minLength: 1,
        dataType: 'json',
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#q').val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $('#q').val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $('<li>')
        .append('<a><span class="flabel">'+item.label+'</span><br /><span class="fvalue">'+item.value+'</span></a>').appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

I hope somebody can help me out here. This has caused hours of frustration.

Comment: Can you post what does your returned json data look like? You should be able to get it by accessing domain.com/json.php?term=test or by using Chrome's network tab from Dev Tools.

Comment: [{"label":"Genus","value":"Cyrtophorus"},{"label":"Species","value":"Cyrtophorus verrucosus"},{"label":"Genus","value":"Nicrophorus"},{"label":"Species","value":"Nicrophorus orbicollis"},{"label":"Species","value":"Nicrophorus pustulatus"},{"label":"Genus","value":"Sphenophorus"},{"label":"Species","value":"Sphenophorus destructor"}] @miro

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 or 3 empty characters between your "value:" and the value. Only on the third entry. That messes up the rest of the json.

So you have `"value":___"Nicrophorus orbicollis"` 
when it should be `"value":"Nicrophorus orbicollis"`

It's hard to see because they are *non-visible* but if you paste one line in a text editor and start deleting the characters you'll see that there are some *empty* characters there.In the text editor, you can also change the encoding to ANSI and you'll see the characters as question marks **("value":??"Nicrophorus orbicollis")**.

Check what your php code spits out.

Comment: they are the same, it might be different is it was `"value   "`

Comment: No. there are 3 invisible characters in the third entry before or after the semicolum. Copy this> `"value":‌​"Nicrophorus orbicollis"` paste it and start deleteing character by character. When you get to the semicolumn you'll see it.

Comment: That's strange... for me the spaces are after the colon. And, I use the json_encode function in php to turn the php array into json. What can i do to fix this? @miro

Comment: Try the following json_encode(array(utf8_encode($data))); If it doesn't work post your PHP code.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not; however i've found a solution a roundabout way... to literally put all the json stuff directly into the php so no encoding needs to happen... ex.:$c .= '{"label":"'.$row['n'].'","value":"'.$row['v'].'"},';    its roundabout but it works! thanks for the help, the spaces were the problem

Comment: Glad you fixed it. You can still try to use json_encode and replace the blank spaces right before you echo it ex: str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),'',$data);